# In magit, how do I close all diffs when using merge preview?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

When using magit I can preview a merge with the command `m` `p`.

This displays a list of open file diffs.  I can close each one individually by navigating to that line and pressing tab.

Is it possible to close all diffs in the buffer at the same time?

Even more useful, to me, would be to close all except those which are in conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "close all diffs" you just want <kbd>M-1</kbd>, which works throughout Magit to collapse sections in the current buffer to the top level only.

Refer to https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Section-Visibility.html